# How to call keras.backend.function from Keras.NET

Tags: python, c#, .net, tensorflow, keras

General question, how can one call the equivalent of keras.backend.function() from C#? Desired goal from python:

```
S = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [
            model.get_layer('S').output])([features])[0]
```

I won't post more of the model, but just any model with some single output activation will do. In C# I am hoping for something that takes a NumPy array like `features` above and will give me the `S` values. I am experimenting with KerasFunction, Keras.Backend.InvokeStaticMethod, but I do not know how to get these to work yet.